# Does Bitbucket have a dark theme/night mode (an option for light text on a dark background)

Tags: bitbucket

I’ve been using [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for a while now, and I find it a bit jarring going between working on my code, where I use a light-on-dark colour scheme, and Bitbucket’s bright white pages.

Does Bitbucket have an option to set the entire site to a darker colour scheme?

**Eight years later:** or, alternatively, any [support for dark mode](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-5/#prefers-color-scheme). See also https://charlesrt.uk/blog/the-dark-web-rises/

Comment: Apparently it's [on the roadmap](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-9949), but there's no release date announced yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the theme used by following these steps:

- Log in to BitBucket
- Navigate to a Repository
- Click the `Admin` tab
- In the top right hand pane select `Appearance Settings`
- Choose your highlight style from the drop down (you can preview the new style on the right hand side)
- Click `Save Settings`

Themes without a white background are:

- **Grey**

  - Friendly
  - Manni
- **Black**

  - Fruity
  - Native
- **Beige**

  - Perldoc

**EDIT**

I don't believe there is way to change the overall theme for BitBucket within their settings but you could use [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en-gb) (a Google Chrome plugin) to change the CSS.  StyleBot instantly changes the CSS and persists your changes for future visits.

Comment: Aha — yeah, that looks great for code on Bitbucket. I actually meant the colour scheme of the entire Bitbucket site, as opposed to just the code.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: I have updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: sure — I’ve been playing around with Stylish, a similar plug-in, as it looks like that’s the only way to change colours for the entire site. Nice to know about an alternative as well. Excellent, cheers.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: No problem - I have to say that StyleBot is pretty slick.

Comment: It seems they have [removed support for this](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/3047/dark-themes-for-viewing-source). :(

Comment: @Kazark: boo, although maybe they'll add support for [operating-system-level dark mode](https://charlesrt.uk/blog/the-dark-web-rises/) to their default design/theme.

Comment: StyleBot has not been updated in over a year, but https://darkreader.org/ is another open source alternative that seems to be working nicely (after only a few minutes of playing around, tbh).

Comment: I feel back in 1666 now, a website I am forced to use everyday that burns my eyes :(

Comment: What if I don't have admin rights for the repo?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you use StyleBot along with this css https://gist.github.com/peterk87/8463882

Comment: I just wish there were a version of this that didn't trash all the syntax highlighting (removing the distracting wood-textured background was easy enough).

Comment: What?! Hell no!